# How to view child browser instance in mobile view in mobile emulation

Tags: mobile, emulation

i am using mobile emulator in chrome to automate mobile view of our company website. When i click on link in the page and it navigates to some other page with new browser window it is not showing the newly opened page in mobile view. How should i solve this issue?